# If you send an email that you already sent, can you say you "resent" it? Same as "resenting" someone?

Tags: differences, orthography, homographs

- I resent my email.
- I resent my mother.
- I resent my email to my mother.

Odd, isn't it?

Comment: Also, someone who tied something first is the first tier :)  English is ambiguous

Comment: resending not resenting (dislike).

Answer (score 15):

As Barrie suggests, a hyphen is useful when writing,
because the two verb forms are **spelled** the same.

However, that's only in writing.

In real English, they're **pronounced** differently, so that's never a problem:

- *re-sent* 'sent again'  is pronounced /ˌri'sɛnt/
- *resent* 'dislike'  is pronounced /rɪ'zɛnt/

Answer (score 14):

In cases such as this where a productive prefix produces a different word that already exists, you would normally leave in the hyphen to disambiguate between the options:

> You say I never copy you on e-mails?  I resent that!
>
> You say you never got the e-mail from me?  I re-sent that!

Comment: Your first sentence describes habitual action so the present tense of "to resent" makes sense. The second sentence is in the past tense so the past tense of "to resend" makes sense. Also, I think most people would be more likely to say _I resent it_, "it" the email, not "that" the other person's statement. I would say that in most non-contrived situations the context would make it clear which one was meant, although using a hyphen certainly eliminates the possibility of resentment being understood!